# Switching from SwiftMQ to IBM MQ in Java application

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Currently, few java applications using SwiftMQ. The new requirement is to replace SwiftMQ with IBM MQ. Java applications uses SwifMQ with JMS. I need to change the java code which should take messages from IBM MQ.
As I am new to MQ, i am not aware of things needs to be considered while migrating to IBM MQ.

Can we use JMS for IBM MQ? 
Can someone list the things that should be considered for migrating.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use JMS with IBM MQ. There is a MQ JMS client provided that provides all the libraries you need to run your JMS application. You haven't said which version of MQ you are planning to use but if it is v8 (the latest) then your application just needs to have /java/lib/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar on the classpath to run.

If your application is to run on a separate machine to the MQ QueueManager then you will need to install the MQ Client, this can be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037500). If it is on the same machine then the MQ install can provide those libraries.

In terms of modifying code, if your existing Java application was written against the JMS API then it should just work as JMS is an API specification. However, there are times when an application might need to set a specific JMS Provider property for example so there might be a few changes you need to make.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything we can use other than JMS? I have seen something like `com.ibm.mq.iiop.jar`.

Comment: If you want to keep within the Java language then you can use the proprietary MQ Java API (javadoc is here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/index.html) or you can write your code using .NET, c, c++, cobol etc.